# Firefox extension not running content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm new to Firefox extension development, and am trying to port the [Tab Stacker](http://youtu.be/VnGjeTxU0Dk) extension from Chrome. So far, I have these files:

```
$ tree
.
├── chrome.manifest
├── content
│   └── content.js
└── install.rdf
```

### chrome.mainfest:

```
content tabstacker  content/
```

### install.rdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>me@gmail.com</em:id>
    <em:version>0.1</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
    <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

    <!-- Firefox -->
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>29.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>29.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Front End MetaData -->
    <em:name>Tab Stacker</em:name>
    <em:description>Moves selected unpinned tabs to the left of the tab bar. Port of the Chrome extension of the same name.</em:description>
    <em:creator>James Wood</em:creator>

    <em:optionsType>2</em:optionsType>

  </Description>
</RDF>
```

(email address hidden)

### content/content.js:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var timeout = -1;
alert('loaded');

tabs.on('activate', function () {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    alert('activate');
    if (!tabs.activeTab.isPinned)
        timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            tabs.activeTab.index = tabs.map(function (t) {
                return t.isPinned;
            }).reduce(function (acc, x) {
                return x ? acc + 1 : acc;
            }, 0);
        }, 1000);
});
```

The `alert` calls are for debugging (I'm not sure which console `console.log` logs to for an extension). But neither are shown, even after restarting the browser. The extension shows up in the add-ons manager. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use SDK modules without using the Add-Ons SDK, otherwise that tree would look quite different. Check out the Add-On SDK documentation and the *Getting Started* section:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK

Comment: Thanks. I'd been following [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development#chrome.manifest), which seems to be from the FF 1.5 days.